# How to include variable inside AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an Ajax request but I wanted to include variables that I have already defined in the data that is sent to the server.

I'm not quite sure how I can escape the data part and put a variable where I have stated...

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: './json/delete.php',                       
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  data: { SD_FieldDisplayName : <VARIABLE HERE>, 
          SD_FieldSeq : <VARIABLE HERE>, 
          SD_TableSeq : <VARIABLE HERE>, 
          SD_ViewName : <VARIABLE HERE> }                      
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(result)          
  {
```

Comment: What's wrong with just putting the identifiers there?

Comment: what is that you are sending as out put? Depends on data if its HTMl you can use result.HTML(); etc

Comment: You don't need to "escape" anything, jQuery will do that.  Just put the variables in the object.

Comment: Well I tried this for example:   data: { SD_FieldDisplayName : test1, SD_FieldSeq : test2, SD_TableSeq : test3, SD_ViewName : test4 } but I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: If you have already defined a variable (e.g. `var myVar = "some text here"`) you can then do `...data: { SD_FieldDisplayName : myVar, etc....}`. Did you try doing that? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yeah, as Rocket said, just throw it in. You're passing a hash/object, so as long as its properly formed, you're golden.

Comment: yep but I get this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Can you post the entire code of the example you just gave (click "edit" below your post to add it to the question)? It sounds like the problem is not what you think.

Comment: @realtek: Did you remember to add a comma at the end of that line?  `async: false, data: {your: variable}, dataType: 'json'`

Comment: oops, sorted it. I forgot a comma at the end of the curly! }, Thanks!!

Comment: Yes rocket Hazmat... that sorted it! How can I mark yours as the answer?

Comment: @realtek: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma after your `data` object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: './json/delete.php',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: { SD_FieldDisplayName : <VARIABLE HERE>,
            SD_FieldSeq : <VARIABLE HERE>,
            SD_TableSeq : <VARIABLE HERE>,
            SD_ViewName : <VARIABLE HERE> },
                  // You need a comma here ^
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result)
    {
    }
});
```

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? Obviously, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reference the variable in the `value` of the `key`:

```
var someVar = 3;

data: { SD_FieldDisplayName : someVar }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You need to include in the variables you want to send through your AJAX request. Here's a stripped example. I've used $.post but $.ajax is essentially the same. It takes the data from a form with the class .formclicked (which other code labels with the class .formclicked. It sends through a 'relations' data with `$_POST['relations']` and a method flag `$_POST['method']`. The first is defined by the form, the second is defined y the submit button in the form, that's not sent by serialise. The serialise function converts the form data in #an_id into a form suitable for AJAX.

> ```
>             // Comments
>             jQuery(document).on('submit','#an_id' ,function(){
>                 $data = jQuery(this).serialize();
>                 var selector = jQuery(this);
>                 $method = jQuery(this).find(".formclicked").attr('value'); // Get clicked form
>                 jQuery.post('your_ajax_form.php', {action:'hook_update',relations:$data, method:$method},
>                     function(answer){
>                         if(jQuery.isNumeric(answer)){
>                             if(answer) {  
>                                    // Response Code Based on Condition
>                             }
>                             else {
>                                     // Handle failures
>                    jQuery(selector).find(".formclicked").removeClass('.formclicked');
>
>                             } 
>                         }
>
>                         else {
>
>                         }
>
>                         return true;
>                     }
>                 );
>                 return false; // Prevent the page from refreshing
>             });
> ```

Comment: That echo statement is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

### Please use this one :

```
var val1;
var val2;
var val3;
var val4;

$.ajax({                                      
  url: './json/delete.php',                       
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  data: { SD_FieldDisplayName : val1 , SD_FieldSeq : val2 , SD_TableSeq : val3 , SD_ViewName : val4 },                     
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(result)          
  {

  }
  });
```

please define variable inside of the function where you want call this ajxa call or global

Comment: This suffers from the same SyntaxError.

Comment: please add common end of data option check again data option

Comment: comma , missing in end of the data option value :  data: { SD_FieldDisplayName : val1 , SD_FieldSeq : val2 , SD_TableSeq : val3 , SD_ViewName : val4 },<<== this one